# How to play many flash (fla) files using javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, for-loop

I have many flash files and need to play continuously on page load i have try some java script but i cant get the event that first flash file end so next flash starts on that event

Comment: In javascript, it is not possible to know when the flash is completely played from swf.

Comment: @Umesh unless you call ExternalInterface from the "playback end" callback function. You can notify JS when a video has stopped.

Comment: yes. It means,   ExternalInterface.call("onFinish"); has to be written in side swf. So, it will call that javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate between Javascript and Actionscript through ExternalInterface.

In your case: listen for the end of the flash film **inside** the flash and then trigger another javascript method call through ExternalInterface:

In Flash:

```
addEventListener("finished", informJS);

private function informJS(e:Event) {
   ExternalInterface.call("onFinish");
}
```

On your Javascript side, you only need the "onFinish" - method that loads the next swf.

Answer (score 0):

Use Actionscript!. From Javascript you won't be able to control Flash events.